# Is it possible to sync ios document using mobileme?

Tags: ios, synchronization, mobileme

Just wondering if it is possible to use mobileme to sync application documents in ios?

If so, is there any sample code out there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can sync to MobileMe as a WebDAV server. Currently there is no built in support to sync app data to MobileMe, that is *rumored* to be part of iOS 5.

In regards to MobileMe as a WebDav server, the first search results on http://DuckDuckGo.com was this: http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/08/13/mounting-mobileme-idisk-using-webdav-and-linux/.